# What does the BuildMacro element do in Visual studio properties and projects?

Tags: c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, vcxproj

I have seen this several times:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
    <SomePropertyName>trunk</SomePropertyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BuildMacro Include="SomePropertyName">
      <Value>$(SomePropertyName)</Value>
    </BuildMacro>
  </ItemGroup>
```

How is this different from just defining the property? To my surprise, there are [only three results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22buildmacro%22%20site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com) for this word on the MSDN, and only one is in English. The one result didn't really help me understand the construct above.

Comment: A `BuildMacro` can have `<EnvironmentVariable>true</EnvironmentVariable>` and be set as an actual environment variable for use by the build tools. Not sure what the other differences are vs. plain user macros.

Answer (score 1):

The `BuildMacro` is used to create custom user macros in property sheet. It could make you manage them in visual studio.

The steps:

1. Open View > Other Windows > Property Manager
2. Open property page under `Configuration|Platform` folder

[image]

Related links:

- [User-defined macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=msvc-160#user-defined-macros)
- [Share or reuse Visual Studio project settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-160)
- [What does BuildMacro actually do](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b6cafb9-c47b-4989-b0bc-0273dd035f77/what-does-buildmacro-actually-do?forum=msbuild)